# Problem with Proxy built to handle CORS issue

Tags: jquery, node.js, reactjs, cors, jersey

Im having CORS issue when local testing between http://localhost:3002 (origin) and http://localhost:8080/configurator (server)

So i decided to build a proxy between them which will append the access-control-allow origins header to any response from server. I seem to be getting an okay response but isnt giving me the body itself. Ignoring the client side code im just trying to test with postman (client software) -> proxy (node express) and end server (jersey)

My request in postman sends to http://localhost:3001/file/ (the proxy) and sends a JSON string content type header set to application/json code for proxy is below

```
var createError = require('http-errors');
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
const request = require('request');
var logger = require('morgan');

var app = express();

// view engine setup
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'pug');

app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

app.use((req, res, next) => {
  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
  next();
});

app.post('/file', (req, res) => {
  request.post(
    { url: 'http://localhost:8080/configurator' },
    (error, response, body) => {
      if (error || response.statusCode !== 200) {
        return res.status(500).json({ type: 'error', message: err.message });
      }

      //console.log("body is"+body)
      //return res.json(body)//res.send(body)
       return res.send(body)
      //return res.send(JSON.parse(body));
      //return res.json(JSON.parse(body));
    }
  )
});

// catch 404 and forward to error handler
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  next(createError(404));
});

// error handler
app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
  // set locals, only providing error in development
  res.locals.message = err.message;
  res.locals.error = req.app.get('env') === 'development' ? err : {};

  // render the error page
  res.status(err.status || 500);
  res.render('error');
});

const PORT = 3001;
app.listen(PORT, () => console.log(`listening on ${PORT}`));

module.exports = app;
```

The proxy forwards the request to my backend and appends CORS header to reponse.

Next ive added endpoints of backend in particular endpoint being used is POST, it simply gets a JSON string then tries to return it.

```
package ie.sidero.resources;

import javax.ws.rs.*;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response;

@Path("/configurator")
public class ConfiguratorFileResource {

    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public String getJsonConfigurationFile(){
        return "File/JSON will get returned here";
    }

    @POST
    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
    public String addJsonConfigurationFile(String jsonConfiguration){
        return jsonConfiguration;
        //return Response.ok("Got the JSON it is: " + jsonConfiguration).header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*").build();
        //return Response.status(Response.Status.OK).entity(jsonConfiguration).build();
    }
}
```

My problem is im only getting an empty string returned. Ive attached two images, one showing console output in proxy saying body is empty and similar result in postman. What am i doing wrong here guys? [image: postman]
[image: console]

**Update:** So my proxy now works with below code:

```
app.use((req, res, next) => {
  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
  req.header('Content-Type', 'application/json');
  next();
});

app.post('/file', (req, res) => {
  request.post(
    { url: 'http://localhost:8080/configurator',
      body: JSON.stringify(req.body)},
    (error, response, body) => {
      if (error || response.statusCode !== 200) {
        return res.status(500).json({ type: 'error', message: err.message });
      }

       //var r = JSON.parse(body);
       //console.log("response body after send is: " +r)

       return res.json(JSON.parse(body));

    }
  )
});
```

Well at least it seems to. Sending requests to localhost:8080/configurator (backend) or localhost:3001/file (proxy) now returns same result when i use postman however im still seeing CORS issue in output when i use my client application and make ajax call, what could the problem be now, im even calling my proxy with ajax call which im attaching below, any help would be great. Any questions just ask guys.

```
$.ajax({
            url: "http://localhost:3001/file", // Url to which the request is send
            type: "POST",             // Type of request to be send, called as method
            data: configJsonEdited,
            contentType: 'application/json',
            dataType: "json",         //Data expected back
            success: function(data)   // A function to be called if request succeeds
            {
                alert("YAY!!!!")
            },
            error: function(xhr, textStatus, errorThrown)
            {
                alert("Damnit!!")
                alert(textStatus);
                alert(errorThrown.toString());
            }
        });
```

Comment: Just also want to add that requesting the backend by itself directly with postman without going through proxy works fine, but wont work if im using my client side application because of the cors issues so i feel something wrong with proxy part

Comment: Do you need to pass through a request body? Is your back end returning 200 even when it doesn't get a request body? I REALLY think you should use an existing proxy however, not try to roll your own. There are NodeJS HTTP proxies already, or you could use nginx and similar. Writing your own is easy for one tiny simple limited case, but there is a lot wrong with this as it is, it should return 502 not 500 with most errors passed through to client, it doesn't handle auth, headers are lost, etc, etc. Why set yourself up for this pain? A good stock proxy will just work

Comment: Hi Michael, there is a lot of validation i must add, that is not what I'm here to ask. Currently im just trying to get bare bones functionality. Ive discovered proxy was never sending the JSON because it wasnt being passed i updated code and console log shows i now get the json data but not sure if im sending it correctly ``` request.post(
    { url: 'http://localhost:8080/configurator',
      data: JSON.stringify(req.body)}, ``` when console log req.body i can see the json

Comment: Yep, I thought it was suspicious you were posting, but not sending through request body, but apparently your back end must still returns 200 then... I STILL think you should not roll your own proxy though, I'd be amazed if `http-proxy` (npm) could not do all the validation you care for, without burdening you with 1,000 potential little issues like forgetting to pass through request body.

Comment: How do i forward the json recieved through the request.post method?

Comment: What 3rd party proxy do recommend, it needs to be configurable?

Comment: It's impossible to advise what proxy would be good for you, I quite like nginx but have no idea if it is suitable for your needs, it sounds like you think you have unusual requirements. If you want to use a node solution though `http-proxy` looks pretty good and will probably get everything right by default instead of doing nothing right by default.

Comment: I tried it, it works, I posted my sample below...

Answer (score 0):

You will be much better off not writing a proxy from scratch. If you really want a nodejs proxy you can use [http-proxy](https://www.npmjs.com/package/http-proxy) something like this:

```js
const http = require('http');
const httpProxy = require('http-proxy');

const proxy = httpProxy.createProxyServer();

const server = http.createServer(function(req, res) {
    proxy.web(req, res, { target: 'http://localhost:8080' });
});

proxy.on('proxyRes', function (proxyRes, req, res) {
    res.setHeader('foo', 'bar');
}).on('error', function (e) {
    console.error(e);
});

server.listen(3001);
```

This is just a dumb example, I butchered into existence from pasting bits of code from [the http-proxy docs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/http-proxy), that error handling is obviously insufficient for production purposes for a start, but it shows you can create a proxy trivially and tinker with the response (in this case I add a header since that's your primary use case).

I just tried this against a server of mine and it passed request body in, and auth, it passes back error and success http responses, and always adds that `foo` header.

Comment: Hi Michael, So both approaches will work, ive managed to get my proxy to work also via testing with postman however im still seeing COR's issue and also 404 not found issue when i try same ajax request from my application

Answer (score 0):

Resolved CORS issue by adding this dependency to my proxy:

https://expressjs.com/en/resources/middleware/cors.html